# Is there an idiomatic R way to normalize a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

The question is as follows: we have a csv file with some abnormal form for data. R is huge, and I'm missing for sure some short solution.

Given a file we read it and get a dataframe of the form below:

```
# id, file, topic, proportion, [topic, proportion]*
0,file1.txt,0,0.01
1,file2.txt,0,0.01,1,0.03
```

Is there any short way to convert this into this dataframe:

```
id      file topic proportion
 0 file1.txt     0       0.01
 1 file2.txt     0       0.01
 1 file2.txt     1       0.03
```

where we have the constant number of columns? The number of topic-proportion pairs is not defined and can be very large. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you reading the data into R? Also, I believe you mean consistent number of columns, not rows.

Comment: Yep, I'm reading a file in, get a dataframe with divergent number of columns, and I want to normalize this data to get a fixed number of columns splitting each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to proceed. I suppose `data` contain the path of your file saved as a `.csv` file:

```
library(plyr)

df        = read.csv(data)
names     = c("id","file","topic","proportion")
extractDF = function(u) setNames(df[,c(1,2,u,u+1)], names)

newDF = ldply(seq(3,length(df)-1,by=2), extractDF)

newDF[complete.cases(newDF),]

#  id      file topic proportion
#1  0 file1.txt     0       0.01
#2  1 file2.txt     0       0.01
#4  1 file2.txt     1       0.03
```

Data are the following, save in `csv` format:

```
# id, file, topic, proportion, [topic, proportion]* 
0,file1.txt,0,0.01 
1,file2.txt,0,0.01,1,0.03
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. Is there any generalized solution, where we do not set literally row indexes? Suppose you can have different lines with different number of rows.

Comment: I never set row indexes but mention columns by their indexes!
This solution will work provided you have lines having 4 or 6 elements as you mentionned in your example.

Comment: Nevertheless is there a way to process rows of arbitrary length?

Comment: It was not the primary question you raised and as such this code answered your question! You mean length of 4, 6, 8, 10, etc (as I understand only the couple (topic, proportion) can be repeated) ?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. I changed the question formulation.

Comment: Here is the generalisation, I guess it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Presuming this is your starting data....

```
mydf <- read.table(
  text = "id, file, topic, proportion, topic, proportion
0,file1.txt,0,0.01
1,file2.txt,0,0.01,1,0.03", 
  header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE) 
mydf
#   id      file topic proportion topic.1 proportion.1
# 1  0 file1.txt     0       0.01      NA           NA
# 2  1 file2.txt     0       0.01       1         0.03
```

You would just need to do....

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("topic", "proportion"), 
             sep = "var.stubs")[, .time_1 := NULL][]
#    id      file topic proportion
# 1:  0 file1.txt     0       0.01
# 2:  0 file1.txt    NA         NA
# 3:  1 file2.txt     0       0.01
# 4:  1 file2.txt     1       0.03
```

Wrap the entire thing in `na.omit` if you don't want the rows that have `NA` values in them.

```
na.omit(
  merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("topic", "proportion"), 
               sep = "var.stubs")[, .time_1 := NULL])
#    id      file topic proportion
# 1:  0 file1.txt     0       0.01
# 2:  1 file2.txt     0       0.01
# 3:  1 file2.txt     1       0.03
```